# Is there any way to find out specific tag values from XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am setting up alert using extended event in which I am pulling out info in XML  format so I got stuck in finding out the values - Object name from this XML.

```
SELECT CAST(data AS XML) AS [result] 
FROM #temp  
WHERE data LIKE '%<text>Abort</text>%'
```

Using this query, I have pulled out those records which gets time out in XML format and through this xml, we need to pull **XYZ** value as object name using T-SQL `<value>XYZ</value></data>`

Output of above select query:

```
<event name="rpc_completed" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2019-02-20T14:42:39.678Z"><data name="cpu_time"><value>15000</value></data><data name="duration"><value>29999325</value></data><data name="physical_reads"><value>0</value></data><data name="logical_reads"><value>363</value></data><data name="writes"><value>0</value></data><data name="result"><value>2</value><text>Abort</text></data><data name="row_count"><value>9</value></data><data name="connection_reset_option"><value>0</value><text>None</text></data><data name="object_name"><value>XYZ</value></data><data name="statement"><value>exec XYZ </value></data><data name="data_stream"><value /></data><data name="output_parameters"><value /></data><action name="transaction_id" package="sqlserver"><value>0</value></action><action name="session_id" package="sqlserver"><value>1381</value></action><action name="server_principal_name" package="sqlserver"><value>sq</value></action><action name="database_name" package="sqlserver"><value>PR</value></action><action name="database_id" package="sqlserver"><value>5</value></action><action name="client_pid" package="sqlserver"><value>32048</value></action><action name="client_hostname" package="sqlserver"><value>RuntimeHost</value></action><action name="client_app_name" package="sqlserver"><value>test</value></action><action name="event_sequence" package="package0"><value>133050</value></action></event>

NA
```

Output should be like this:

```
Object Name
XYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nodes` to filter the items inside your xml by attribute value and then `value` to extract the data you need:

```
;with x as(
    SELECT CAST(data AS XML) AS [result] 
    FROM #temp  
    WHERE data LIKE '%<text>Abort</text>%'
)
select 
    t.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as object_name
from
    x
cross apply 
    [result].nodes('//data[@name = "object_name"]/value') t(s)
```

Result:

[image]

---

*Edit*

One approach to retrieve `database_name` is adding another `nodes` filtering on `action` tags. To get the `timestamp` you can just add a `value` in the `select` clause specifying the correct xpath expression:

```
;with x as(
    SELECT CAST(data AS XML) AS [result] 
    FROM #temp  
    WHERE data LIKE '%<text>Abort</text>%'
)
select 
      t.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as [object_name]
    , u.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as [database_name]
    , [result].value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [timestamp]
from
    x
        cross apply 
    [result].nodes('//data[@name = "object_name"]/value') t(s)
        cross apply  
    [result].nodes('//action[@name = "database_name"]/value') u(s)
```

Results with `database_name` and `timestamp`:

[image]

Comment: Am trying to add database name and timestamp as well but no luck using nodes

Comment: confused about timestamp in above output because actual timestamp in extended event is different and in XML its different . I was try to convert it to date time but no success.